# calling C/C++ functions of a library compiled with g++, wthin a program compiled with gcc

Tags: gcc, g++

I have a set of software library modules which are developed in c++.  So, I use g++ to compile my software.

This has to be used by various existing applications which are written in C and compiled with gcc.

When the other teams used g++ to compile their code, they started getting lot of compiler errors due to strict type checking rules of c++. This broke their applications. Worse still, they are using some 3rd party library code, which cannot be compiled using g++.

if they use gcc, then there are linker errors (unresolved symbols).

so, my question is...
"Is there a way for my library code to be linked with their applications, without changing the respective compilers?  That is, i still have to use g++, since i use classes/objects heavily in my code, and they have no choice of using g++, which will break their application?".

Thank you for kind help.

regards,
Ravindra

Comment: Linking pre-compiled C++ code basically requires you to use the same exact compiler.  There are some approaches that can work (use plain-old-data types or serialization, with an extern "C"-only interface), but there's a lot of stuff that simply won't work and will break, if you try to use your public interface as-is.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you may be experiencing could be the result of different versions of g++ having different ABI formats.  at very least, don't expect versions of G++ prior to 4.1 to work with code compiled with 4.1 or later.

Intermingling C and C++ requires that the C++ code all export a C compatible interface.  This is done by declaring free functions (cannot be used on classes) with the `extern "C"` specifier.  [(some notes on the c++ faq lite_](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html)

```
extern "C" {
  #include "c_language_headers.h"

  int c_accessible_function(int);

  struct c_accessible_datatype { };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I am already doing this part

Comment: I am using #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" #endif part.  But inspite of this, I was under the impression that both the modules (the c code that calls and the c++ library) should be compiled with g++ only.  Correct me, if I am wrong.

Comment: As per the link suggested by you, it is saying the following:     *  You must use your C++ compiler when compiling main() (e.g., for static initialization)
* Your C++ compiler should direct the linking process (e.g., so it can get its special libraries)
    * Your C and C++ compilers probably need to come from same vendor and have compatible versions (e.g., so they have the same calling conventions)
As for me the points 1 & 2 cannot be met, due to external constraints.  Please suggest.

Comment: the code that has the main() function is the c code, which is going to be compiled using gcc.  My library has to be compiled with g++, since I am using classes.  However, I am providing a wrapper interface via extern "C".

Comment: OK, does it mean, I can let my library users "compile" using gcc, but when they link, should they use g++ ?